# Stop vm with Powershell if my software does not run

Tags: azure, powershell

I have a vm under azure that runs my software for a client, I want to automatically stop the vm if my software does not run (My software does not run means for me the client does not use the vm and i can stop-it and restart-it the day after)

I know that azure offers the possibility to stop automatically a vm (Auto-shutdown) but I do not want to stop the vm only if my software does not run

to stop my vm, I use this code:

```
Stop-AzureRmVM -Name $VmName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Force
```

Comment: What is your question/issue?

Comment: Test with [Get-Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-process?view=powershell-6) if your software is still running and if not shutdown the vm ?

Comment: @I.TDelinquent How to know with powershell if my softwar run befor stop the vm :)

Comment: @m-mas Check for the running process using `Get-Process`? Without more information, we can't offer any specific help.

Comment: @I.TDelinquent i'm sorry, i will explain-it again : From Azure portal, i want to launch cloud shell, connect to my vm, check for running process and stop the vm if the process of my software does not work. So i can't find how to execute Get-Process from Azure portal to a specific VM. Thank's for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ***Issue:  I can't find how to execute Get-Process from Azure portal to a***
>   ***specific VM***

If you want to run Run PowerShell scripts in your Windows VM, you can use the **`run command`** feature on Azure Portal. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/run-command.

[image]

Comment: @m-mas Do you have any other concerns?